# Why have both User and Profile models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I've seen many references on SO and the web where people are using both User and Profile models in there apps (particularly, but not always, when they are using the devise gem).  All the examples I've seen are has_one relationships.  Why not just putt all the Profile info in the User model?

Comment: FWIW I very very rarely use a Profile.. I just add the fields I want to the devise User object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User table is used in every action. But many times, profile information is not.

So if you are planning to add information that you will use almost in each request (like first_name, last_name) put them on users table.

But there no reason to put, let's say, age, country, state etc.. They will cause performance problems later.

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on what your goal is. If you only want to have a profile page - a single view associated with a user's profile - what I'd normally do is have `Users#show` be the profile page. This is probably the most common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think primarily because everyone uses the devise gem to make/handle Users, and it's just easier to make a new Profile model than configure devise.